# reactjs -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error,please help me.

```
func = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["PropTypes"].func,
object = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["PropTypes"].object,
arrayOf = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["PropTypes"].arrayOf
```

This is package.json

```
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"react": "^16.1.0",
"react-dom": "^16.1.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router": "^3.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
```

This is the code

```
LoginForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  btnText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. Please mention where the error points to and provide the relevant code

Comment: updated code @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Where are you importing PropTypes from

Comment: i am using this "import PropTypes from 'prop-types';"  in main.js file.@ShubhamKhatri

Comment: You need to import it wherever you are using PropTypes

Comment: i did it in all files where PropType is.But still same error.@ShubhamKhatri

Comment: I guess error in bundle.js where the webpack packages are loading @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package.json shows you have "prop-types" installed.

So at the top of your file you need to import PropTypes like so:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

and that should fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

In react 16 propTypes have been moved to a seperate package.  So check whether you import to Proptypes is correct as per the version you use

Answer (score 0):

Using React Router 3.2.0 resolves this issue:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5605​​